# Scala xml RewriteRules appear to be applied out of order

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to put together an object that contains a bunch of `RewriteRules` and can return a `RuleTransformer`.  That works, but for some reason the last two RewriteRules (and others, for all I know) seem to be applied out of order.

This is a simplified set of the rules I am including the RuleTransformer I'm returning:

```
  def getTransformer(): RuleTransformer = {
    val contentSourceNodeLabels = List("contentgroup", "byline")
    val copyrightReplacementMapping = Map(
      """Version 1""".r  -> "All rights reserved. Used with permission.",
      """Version 2""".r    -> "By example.com, © Acme Co. All rights reserved. Used with permission.",
      "".r                -> "By example.com, © Acme Co. All rights reserved. Used with permission."
    )
    val metadataNodeOrder = List(
      "title",
      "subtitle",
      "abstract",
      "copyrighttext"
    )

    new RuleTransformer(
      new alterCopyrightNode("contentitem", contentSourceNodeLabels, copyrightReplacementMapping),
      new alterMetadataOrder(metadataNodeOrder)
    )
  }
```

Note that the last label in the metadataNodeOrder is "copyrighttext".  In order to correctly order the metadata elements, `alterMetadataOrder` needs the copyright element label to be changed from "copyright" to "copyrighttext" - which is what the `alterCopyrightNode` rule does.  So the order of these rules is significant.

I added a `println()` to each of those rules and, in fact, they do seem to be run out of order:

```
> run data/articles_20120711.xml

data/articles_20120711.xml:
  ..formatted
  >> [alterMetadataOrder]: reordered child nodes
  >> [alterCopyrightNode]: corrected copyright text
  ..normalized
  ..NORMALIZED XML FAILED VALIDATION
  ..done
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 20, 2016 3:26:33 PM
```

It looks like the [Scala RulesTransformer](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/transform/RuleTransformer.scala) basically takes the rules as a Seq and does a `.foldLeft` on them, so I don't understand how I'm getting the results I'm seeing.  Any ideas?

```
class RuleTransformer(rules: RewriteRule*) extends BasicTransformer {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] =
    rules.foldLeft(super.transform(n)) { (res, rule) => rule transform res }
}
```

Comment: Your question could be better if you gave us a self contained example. You're not showing for example how you're running this `RuleTransformer` which may be one cause of the problem.